# Populate TextBox with cell reference when cell is clicked while UserForm is open

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a small VBA project, part of it is a userform.

One of the TextBoxes on the form requires the user to provide a cell reference

While the UserForm is open, if the TextBox is currently selected, and user clicks on a cell in the workbook, I'd like the TextBox to be populated with a reference to that cell.

(the same way as for example "New Formatting Rule: Use a formula to determine which cells to format" formula input is done)

Is there any way of solving this?

Important: the macro is not workbook specific, so I can't put anything in Workbook_Open event etc.

Comment: There  a control for this RefEdit http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson20.htm

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you post it as a full answer I will tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a control for this RefEdit available in the toolbox.  Excellent article here to get you started ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson20.h‌​tm

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using [Application.InputBox()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx)

You can specify `type:=8` and it allows the user to choose a range, from which you can get the `.Address` property

---

The other option is the RefEdit control in the link provided by Nathan_Sav - this is another good option (full disclosure - I am affiliated with OzGrid)